# How to connect to a paired audio Bluetooth device using Windows UWP API?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, bluetooth

I want to create a console alternative to the 'Bluetooth and Other devices' dialog that is built into Windows for controlling Bluetooth devices. Using [Windows.Devices.Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-19041) API, I can pair and unpair devices. However, Bluetooth audio devices also have a connection feature (see the screenshot below). I would like my application to replicate what happens when I press the **Connect** button in this UI dialog.
[image]

### Update

Currently, there is no API that could be used to solve my problem. There is a very good [discussion on Github](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/issues/132) about this topic that contains descriptions of available solutions and explains why they don't work.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no public API to do exactly the same thing. However it can be simulated by using BluetoothSetServiceState() function.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, thank you for your reply. Do you know if there is an analog of `BluetoothSetServiceState()` function for UWP apps? Maybe `Windows.Devices.Enumeration` namespace have something similar?

Comment: I do no think there is any analog.

Answer (score 6):

So far, I have found a workaround that allows Windows to connect to Bluetooth audio devices.
It is based on an [answer from Bernard Moeskops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642702/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-a-bluetooth-device-with-a-powershell-script-on-win/53648715#53648715). However, to make it work, the following needs to be taken into account:

- Bluetooth audio devices can be registered as multiple PnP devices, and you need to toggle each one.
- It seems that waiting for 10 seconds between enabling and disabling is not necessary.
- "Disable-PnpDevice" and "Enable-PnpDevice" commands require admin rights.

I have created a PowerShell script that worked for me (you need to change the `$headphonesName` variable to the name of your audio device):

```
# "Disable-PnpDevice" and "Enable-PnpDevice" commands require admin rights
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Substitute it with the name of your audio device.
# The audio device you are trying to connect to should be paired.
$headphonesName = "WH-1000XM3"

$bluetoothDevices = Get-PnpDevice -class Bluetooth

# My headphones are recognized as 3 devices:
# * WH-1000XM3
# * WH-1000XM3 Avrcp Transport
# * WH-1000XM3 Avrcp Transport
# It is not enough to toggle only 1 of them. We need to toggle all of them.
$headphonePnpDevices = $bluetoothDevices | Where-Object { $_.Name.StartsWith("$headphonesName") }

if(!$headphonePnpDevices) {
    Write-Host "Coudn't find any devices related to the '$headphonesName'"
    Write-Host "Whole list of available devices is:"
    $bluetoothDevices
    return
}

Write-Host "The following PnP devices related to the '$headphonesName' headphones found:"
ForEach($d in $headphonePnpDevices) { $d }

Write-Host "`nDisable all these devices"
ForEach($d in $headphonePnpDevices) { Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $d.InstanceId -Confirm:$false }

Write-Host "Enable all these devices"
ForEach($d in $headphonePnpDevices) { Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $d.InstanceId -Confirm:$false }

Write-Host "The headphones should be connected now."

# After toggling, Windows "Bluetooth devices" dialog shows the state of the headphones as "Connected" but not as "Connected voice, music"
# However, after some time (around 5 seconds), the state changes to "Connected voice, music".
Write-Host "It may take around 10 seconds until the Windows starts showing audio devices related to these headphones."
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for my B&W PX7 headset as well, with this one-line change:

`$headphonesName = "PX7 Bowers & Wilkins"`

I don't suppose you know how to define and consume the headset name as a command-line argument to the script?  My Powershell skills are... um... lacking, or I would update the answer to make it more generic...

Comment: Added to [github](https://github.com/Stabledog/windows-bluetooth-hack)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/m2jean/ToothTray/ is the correct way to connect and disconnect bluetooth audio device by program and I think Win10 Win11 also use this way. But this tool has a bug, can not work properly in Win11. Call IMMDeviceEnumerator::EnumAudioEndpoints, change parameter EDataFlow from eCaptuer to eAll, can fix the bug. And I also code in csharp, everything is ok.

Comment: The ToothTray doesn't disconnect audio devices properly - [more details](https://github.com/m2jean/ToothTray/issues/10). However, the connection functionality works. Thank you very much for creating this tool.